# HTML / CSS Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, web, drop-down-menu

I would like to have 5 divs, inline, with the third one showing a dropdown menu beneath it when hovered on. When I hover over the third div my dropdown menu appears, but it appears to the left of the page on the next line, rather than directly beneath the third div.

HTML:

```
<div class="option">One</div>
<div class="option">Two</div>
<div class="option">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="onHover">Three
            <div class="showMenu">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a></br>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a></br>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="option">Four</div>
<div class="option">Five</div>
```

CSS:

```
.option {
    display: inline;
}

#container {
    display: inherit;
}

.onHover {
    display: inline;
}

.showMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.onHover:hover .showMenu {
    display: block;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Go read up on what the reference point for absolute positioning is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give relative position to the parent of absolute & then position the menu with top/left. You might also need to adjust the width or use ellipsis.

```css
.option {
    display: inline;
}

#container {
    display: inherit;
    position: relative;
}

.onHover {
    display: inline;
}

.showMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:1em;
    left:0px;    
}

.onHover:hover .showMenu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">One</div>
<div class="option">Two</div>
<div class="option">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="onHover">Three
            <div class="showMenu">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a></br>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a></br>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="option">Four</div>
<div class="option">Five</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must define the positions for the absolute elements :

```
.showMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:15px; // add this
    left:0;   // add this
}
```

and to make it on the left of specific element you must make this element position is relative

```
.onHover {
    display: inline;
    position:relative; // add this
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9dxn0cn8/

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to make

```
.option { position: relative; }
```

You need to reed about position:absolute: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Also always good idea is look to some examples:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this , i am updated in your jsfiddle

```
code
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mhrjnsa1/jpwqcxtj/3/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.option {
    display: inline;
}

#container {
    display: inherit;
}

.onHover {
    display: inline;
}

.showMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:70px;
}

.onHover:hover .showMenu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">One</div>
<div class="option">Two</div>
<div class="option">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="onHover">Three
            <div class="showMenu">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a></br>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a></br>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="option">Four</div>
<div class="option">Five</div>
```